# Проблема с data-id

Tags: javascript

Суть в том, что data-id не соответствует. Не могу понять почему.
Допустим находим все элементы с таким классом у которых есть data-id разный.

```
const temp = document.getElementsByClassName('Square');
```

Когда делаем

```
console.log(temp) //смотрим в консоли на data-id первого элемента
console.log(temp[0].dataset.id)
```

data-id не совпадают.

В общем, мне нужно присвоить каждому элементу со своим data-id свою картинку. Но из-за несовпадения присваиваются хаотично.

P.S. Решение только на vanilla.js. Спасибо.

Comment: может добавите полный код (html + js) вместо такого абстрактного ничего?

Comment: Я скорее всего понял свою ошибку. Я пишу на reactjs, и перемешиваю массив постоянно при rerender'е компонента. Поэтому выходят разные data-id